# Closing a command prompt in powershell

Tags: powershell, process, pid

I have a powershell script, which opens up many cmd.exe processes, having different titles.
I wish to close only one of these processes. I cannot use

```
Get-Process cmd | Stop-Process
```

as all the processes shut down. Is there a way to set the process ID for each process, so I can identify it later and shut it down? Or is there any other way to identify the process by its title name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the information about a process in a variable.
Later you can stop the process with those informations

```
$XYProcess = Start-Process "cmd.exe" -PassThru

Stop-Process $XYProcess.ID
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not know of the -PassThru parameter. How do I pipe commands to this process? Like say I want cmd to start and execute ipconfig.

Comment: You can run ipconfig in powershell. You don't need cmd

Comment: I know. That was just an example. I just wanted to know if it was possible to pass an argument to a process. I figured out what I needed anyway. Thanks.